# Nested QVector pointer memory handling

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, windows-7, qt5

I've inherited a substantial Qt5 project, where the accumulative memory leakage is becoming a serious issue. (Yes, memory leakage should rarely be tolerated but with real life budget and time constraints...).

This GUI reads image data into objects of a voxel class, to be displayed graphically. The data comes either from file or buffer (if acquired live) and is stored as a nest qvector, ie:

```
QVector < QVector <Voxel *> > cVoxel;
```

*When an image is read from file, `cVoxel` is initialized using `QVector.resize(0)`.*

```
cVoxel.resize(0);
```

*When an image save to file is opened, a local `Voxel` pointer is created and pushed to the end of `cVoxel`, once for every pixel so looping over all rows and columns:*

```
for (iRow = 0; iRow < nRows; ++iRow)
{
   for (iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; ++iCol)
   {
      Voxel *v = new Voxel;
      cVoxel[iRow].push_back(v);
      // Code for reading data into cVoxel removed here
      ...
   }
}
```

Courtesy of the useful comments below, I've now had some success in seeing memory usage **decrease** in the Windows Task Manager, by nesting destruction of the cVoxel QVector in my CTOR. Along the lines of:

```
for (iRow = 0; iRow < nRows; iRow++)
{
    for (iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; iCol++)
    {
        delete cVoxel[iRow][iCol];
    }
}
```

Ideally, a major rewrite is the best solution. But in the real world, I'll have to try and fix the bigger leaks and hope that's enough until there's enough resources available for a more ideal solution.

- I've looked at memory leakages in `Voxel` itself, but there's nothing obvious there.
- My research reveals that looking at the Windows Task Manager for memory consumption isn't entirely reliable (Win7 isn't a Real-Time OS..), but if opening a file increases the application memory consumption from 16M to 81.5M, then surely there should be **some** memory decrease if the allocated memory in `cVoxel` is successfully released? If I keep opening and shut images, the app's memory consumption keeps increasing in similar step. It never decreases after closing any/all opened images.
- Right now, there's no attempt to release any memory assigned (using the new operator) to `cVoxel`. I have tried a few approaches (and read to learn more), but so far litte luck.
- QVector is excellent at taking care of it's own memory handling, but I'm stuck with this nest QVector setup, and simply relying on QVector's squeeze(), resize(), or similar will only leak memory (which is already the case for other variables in the project.. I have run the project through Visual Leak Detector, so I've an idea which are the serious culprits, and which ones are small fish)

**----EDIT ----**

Apologies for the messy ad-hod commenting below, but this is certainly helping me reduce the memory leakages (complete stoppage will hopefully happen in due course..).

I've edited in-line above to (hopefully) make this post clearer, and removed my best case effort as it had no impact on the memory leak. The significant alteration above are the (2) brief paragraphs in italics.

I also need to investigate @richardcitter (sp?) polymorphism related suggestion.

**--- EDIT3 ---**

Removed Edit2, posted that (new) question separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223804/unique-ptr-qvector-resize-throws-error-2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted).

Also, I'm pretty confident the answer below should fix this question - I just need to figure out how to use `qvector.resize()` or find a workaround to it.

Comment: You use a loop within a loop to create the objects. Have you thought about that for destroying them as well?

Comment: Is `Voxel` polymorphic? If not then store `Voxel` rather than `Voxel *`.

Comment: Don't expect to see _any_ decrease in process size after free in things like Task Manager. (Though the second time you load your thing in the same process, your process size shouldn't change much.) Could happen, but unlikely. Use something like valgrind to detect leaks.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I did, but it didn't work. I'll try again but confusingly if I do cVoxel.size() I get 80, but cVoxel[0].size() I get 160. rows = cols = 80. So I would've expected both .size() calls to yield 80?

Comment: Do you perhaps pre-allocate entries in the inner vector, for example by calling [`resize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize)? Oh and you *do* push back the inner vectors into the outer (e.g.  `cVoxel.push_back(QVector<Voxel*>())`)? Your code does not show that.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Apologies, missed your reply. Voxel inherits from QObject, so strictly speaking: Yes, it's polymorphic. But I'm fairly sure I don't use it as such. Ie I only ever point at Voxel using *Voxel.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I'm sorry, I thought I was careful to include full snippets (if that makes sense). Just tried nested deletion now memory **is** dropping after each image is closed. It's now <4M lost/image, an improvement.

Comment: If it polymorphic then use `QVector < QVector <std::unique_ptr<Voxel>> > cVoxel;`  Then you will get automatic deletion.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Not sure what pre-allocate means in this context? But QVector.resize() is called upon initialization (arg = 0, as in my post), but also each time a file or buffer is opened. During acquisition (so 100s of buffers/sec) that's a real concern. And I will update my post to better reflect the relevant code.

Comment: @RichardCritten: Sorry, are you recommending I use std::unique_ptr (etc) instead of my current usage? I take it that my Voxel class **is** polymorhpic, as it's inheriting from a parent class (QObject), regardless of my choice of class pointer?

Comment: If `cVoxel` owns the `Voxel` objects and `Voxel` is polymorphic  then use an owning pointer in the vector(s); if the ownership is unique (not shared) then `std::unique_pointer` is appropriate.  You can still pass raw (observer) pointers to functions that need raw pointers using `std::unique_ptr::get`, which returns a raw pointer but does __not__ transfer ownership.

Comment: When you do `cVoxel.resize(0)` you set the size of `cVoxel` to zero, it is now *empty*. Any indexing into the vector (like you do with `cVoxel[iRow].push_back(v)`) will be *out of bounds!* Indexing out of bounds leads to *undefined behavior* and bad things happening.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications (@RichardCritten, @Someprogrammerdude). I think ownership is unique; Undefined behaviour may lead to a swift crash (if I'm lucky..!), so best be safe and check beforehand. But if doing `QVector.resize(0)` near object initialization, do I risk having a QVector that's too small if I later start doing a lot of `.push_back()` on it? The code's guilty of that right now, but has seemingly worked "fine" for some time though.. (Is that a case of being "unlucky" and not seeing any crashes just yet?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SomeProgrammerDude: You got me 9/10 towards the solution.

As outlined in [a connected SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48223804/unique-ptr-qvector-resize-throws-error-2280-attempting-to-reference-a-deleted), I decided against smart pointers in the end. The above solution introduced (for me) the issue of the compiler trying to reference a deleted function. Otherwise it is correct with a couple of modifications:

```
QVector < QVector <Voxel *> > cVoxel;
```

Initialisation:

```
cVoxel.resize(0);
```

Memory assignment:

```
{
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
   {
      cVoxel.push_back( QVector <Voxel *> () );
      for (int j = 0 ; j < cols ; ++j)
      {
         Voxel *v = new Voxel;
         cVoxel[i].push_back(v);
      }
   }
}
```

Finally DTOR releasing the memory:

```
   int iRow, iCol;
   for (iRow = 0; iRow < rows; iRow++)
   {
      for (iCol = 0; iCol < cols; iCol++)
      {
           delete cVoxel[iRow][iCol];
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the undefined behavior and to properly make sure that you don't need to make any extra allocations, you can preallocate the number of elements in the vectors. You already do this when you call `resize(0)`, but instead of setting the size you really need, you make the size zero, you make the vector empty.

I would suggest something like this instead:

First use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as suggested by Richard Critten:

```
QVector < QVector < std::unique_ptr <Voxel> > > cVoxel;
```

<sub>If Qt have its own unique pointer type you could use that instead.</sub>

Then when you create the you use [`resize`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize) to set the *actual* size of the vectors:

```
cVoxel.resize(nRows);
```

Then you can use plain indexes into the vector. Set the size for the inner vectors as well:

```
for (iRow = 0; iRow < nRows; ++iRow)
{
   cVoxel[iRow].resize(nCols);  // Resize to the number of columns

   for (iCol = 0; iCol < nCols; ++iCol)
   {
      cVoxel[iRow][iCol].reset(new Voxel);  // Create the actual Voxel object

      // Code for reading data into cVoxel here
      ...
   }
}
```

Since you use `std::unique_ptr` (or the Qt equivalent) the memory managed by the `std::unique_ptr` object will be automatically free'd once the object is destructed. So no more memory leaks, when the `cVoxel` vector goes out of scope or is otherwise destructed, so will your `Voxel` objects be.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - I read the links and smart pointers makes a lot of sense! But I can't figure out how to resolve an error with the `cVoxel...reset(new Voxel)` line though. I'm getting a `C2664 cannot convert argument 1 from 'Voxel *' to 'Voxel **'`. It's puzzling that it's expecting a pointer to a pointer?

Comment: @PhilPhil I made a mistake with the `std::unique_ptr` type, it should be `std::unique_ptr <Voxel>` instead.

Comment: Ahh, I should've seen that from the error message itself. Thank you!

Comment: I've managed to implement unique_ptr in all the cases related to my Voxel memory leaks. Unfortunately, I'm now getting complaints from qvector, saying `error: C2280: .... attempting to reference a deleted function` for a specific use of `cVoxel.resize(nCols)`. If I comment it out and re-compile, I see the same error elsewhere, where the same `cVoxel.resize()` call is made. I'll update the original post with a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Researching this error, I keep seeing "unique_ptrs cannot be copied." Which makes sense, but I thought calling `qvector.resize()` which is what the above error source is doing, would delete unused objects, not try to do any copying? ...Although looking on step away from the complaining line within _qvector.h_, I see this line in _memory_: `unique_ptr(const _Myt&) = delete;`.

Comment: [QVector.resize() documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize) States: _"Sets the size of the vector to size. If size is greater than the current size, elements are added to the end; the new elements are initialized with a default-constructed value."_ **Default-constructed value** in turn means: _"For most value types, this simply means that a value is created using the default constructor"_    Anyway around this, or should I be looking at using one of the eight(!) smart pointers available in Qt? It feels like I'm so close though...

Comment: Sorry, final comment from me: Most of the time, the image size is 80 x 80. So most calls to `.resize()` are a one off, or to free memory ahead of a screen refresh. Although in the future image size will become 400 x 400, so there's an incentive to find a lasting solution to these leaks :-P