# unique_ptr, qvector.resize() throws error 2280 attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, windows-7, qt5, smart-pointers, qvector

To prevent scope creep (on a [previous Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48167985/nested-qvector-pointer-memory-handling)), I've isolated the above error.

My Voxel class definition:

```
#ifndef VOXEL_H
#define VOXEL_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QVector>
#include <iostream>
include <memory>

class Voxel : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Voxel();
    ~Voxel();
};

#endif // VOXEL_H
```

The main file which triggers the error:

```
#include <voxel.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QVector < QVector <std::unique_ptr <Voxel> > > cVoxel;

    cVoxel.resize(0);

    int rows = 80, cols = 80;

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
       cVoxel[i].resize(cols);
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
       {
          cVoxel[i][j].reset(new Voxel);
       }
    }
}
```

The line ultimately throwing the error is:

```
cVoxel[i].resize(cols);
```

The full error trace: (which doesn't say that the error ultimately comes main)

[image]

There are other Questions ([that are helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=attempting%20to%20reference%20a%20deleted%20function)) about this error but I can't fully understand how to resolve it. It would seem that `qvector.resize()` is attempting to reallocate and likely using a copy constructor which is then throwing this error? I could manually free the memory instead of using the above function, but the whole ideal of using smart pointers is to avoid memory leaks... I started using unique_ptr to address substantial leaking.

---

I'm using QtCreator 4.4.0 and Qt 5.6.2, 64-bits.

**--- EDIT ---**

If I replace `QVector` with `std::vector`, ie cVoxel is created as:

```
std::vector < std::vector <std::unique_ptr <Voxel> > > cVoxel;
```

Then the program crashes in the outer for loop, at:

```
cVoxel[i].resize(cols);
```

Debugging reveals that:

> Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: C:\windows\system32\MSVCP140D.dll
>   File: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE\vector
>   Line: 1234
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion
>   failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.

I can get the code to work by resizing cVoxel to 80 rather than 0. But it appears there's a subtle difference between how [`QVector.resize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html#resize) and [`std::vector.resize()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/resize/) operate. Reading the docs for each, they seemed identical.

Comment: Use std::vector instead of QVector.

Comment: I tried it on my isolated project: linker error (doh). However, on my actual project the project runs and gets as far as reading an image before crashing. Which is a step forward, I'm betting the crashing is my fault and not `std::vector` nor `std::unique_ptr` :-) Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) cannot be copied (only moved or move-assigned):

> The class (`unique_ptr`) satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and
>   MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible
>   or CopyAssignable.

The copy-constructor and copy-assignment are deleted in `unique_ptr` hence the error. Copying is implicitly required by `cVoxel[i].resize(cols)`.
You could use `QVector<QVector<Voxel>>` as an alternative.

Another thing: calling `cVoxel[i].resize(cols)` after `cVoxel.resize(0)` is out-of-bounds. You probably need `cVoxel.resize(rows)`.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is the source of the error. For posterity, I avoided using smart pointers for my project (fixing the most obvious leaks manually instead).  This was because of budget/time restraints. I'll definitely be using smart pointers for any future programming project of a similar scope though.